# Consume service or database in WSO2 CustomGatewayJWTGenerator

Tags: wso2

I wanted to know if it is possible to connect to an external database or service from the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim/blob/master/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/test/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator.java

Can we propagate ENV variables to the class, for example with the url of the service to invoke? How to know the service to invoke (depending if sandbox or production)?

Additionaly, is there anyway to access the OAuth scope in this class? Is it possible with JWTValidationInfo scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an env value or a system property to this class.

1. Environment variable: Set the env value to the shell.

> System.getenv("ENDPOINT")

2. System Property: When starting the server you can set the system property as ./api-manager.sh -DENDPOINT="https://localhost:9090"

> System.getProperty("ENDPOINT")

- You can get the key type which comes as production or sandbox as follows.

> jwtInfoDto.getKeyType()

- You can get the scopes from here.

> jwtInfoDto. getJwtValidationInfo().getScopes();

Comment: Hi Pubci. Thanks for your response.
So, the recommended way would be to invoke a REST API from that class to obtain my custom claims. Any library recommendation to make those API calls? Thinking about possible library conflicts with wso2. If I wanted to connect to a database, I have to use standard JDBC right?

I was also wondering about the DEMO dependency versions. (org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.gateway:9.0.174, nimbus-jose-jwt:7.3.0.wso2v1, and org.eclipse.osgi.services:3.5.100.v20160504-1419). Are these versions aligned with the 4.1.0 apim? Could not find info about this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will have to call the endpoint from that class. You can use a cache to improve the latency and to avoid multiple calls. For APIM v4.1.0, you can use carbon.apimgt version 9.20.74. Other libraries are okay